# Explicitly specifying generic type C#

Tags: c#, generics, types, explicit

I want to iterate through the properties of a generic type which might have a look like this:

```
Class A
{
    public List<int> example1 { get; set; }
    string example2 { get; set; }
}
```

the `int` and `string` types above might also be any another value or reference type, am using the below code to do the job but it shows error:

> The type arguments for method 'TestProject.Program.FillCodesFromId(T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly in the highlighted line*

```
static void FillCodesFromId<T, S>(T input)
        where T : new()
        where S : new()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        foreach (var item in type.GetProperties())
        {
            Type tempType = item.PropertyType;
            if (tempType is IEnumerable<S>)
            {
                IEnumerable<S> list = item.GetValue(input) as IEnumerable<S>;
                foreach (var listItem in list)
                {
                    if (IsClassOrStruct(listItem.GetType()))
                    {
                        FillCodesFromId(listItem); //shows error
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (IsClassOrStruct(tempType))
            {
                FillCodesFromId(item.GetValue(input)); //shows error
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var subItem in item.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false))
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated, 
Thanks

Comment: `FillCodesFromId<T,S>(listItem)`, since it cannot guessfrom listItem what S is :)

Comment: You are always going to have to supply T and S explicitly because there is no way for the compiler to infer S.

Comment: As a side note, in case you aren't aware, be careful of if you hae `S` is `char` - `string`s implement `IEnumerable<char>`!

Comment: It is not generic unless you specify `class<T> { List<T> example1 { get; set; } }`. Please update question _with actual code_. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can "fool" the compiler using an Optional Argument which you will never have to supply
(except inside this method)

I don't know if solution is accepted by you but at least you don't have to supply the argument...

```
static void FillCodesFromId<T, S>(T input, S unused = default(S))
        where T : new()
        where S : new()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        foreach (var item in type.GetProperties())
        {
            Type tempType = item.PropertyType;
            if (tempType is IEnumerable<S>)
            {
                IEnumerable<S> list = item.GetValue(input) as IEnumerable<S>;
                foreach (var listItem in list)
                {
                    FillCodesFromId(listItem, default(S)); 
                }
            }

        }
    }
```